# When is the image of an entire function all of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functions

Little Picard Theorem:

> If a function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is entire and non-constant, then the set of values that $f(z)$ assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.

Define "*Picard-0 functions*" to be the functions which are entire, non-constant and their image is $\mathbb{C}$. Define "*Picard-1 functions*" to be the functions which are entire, non-constant and their image is $\mathbb{C}$ without a single point.

Some elementary examples of Picard-0 functions are $\sin$ and $\cos$. However, $\exp$ is a well known example of a Picard-1 function.

Just by looking at the power series expansions at the origin,
$$\sin z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{Im}(i^n)\frac{z^n}{n!},\quad z\in\mathbb{C},$$
$$\cos z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{Re}(i^n)\frac{z^n}{n!},\quad z\in\mathbb{C},$$
$$\exp z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!},\quad z\in\mathbb{C},$$
it is not immediately clear whether they are Picard-0 functions or Picard-1 functions, given that they are entire and non-constant (this is just an illustrative example). (In the series, $0^0=1$ was assumed.)

If $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and $f$ is entire and non-constant, is it possible to state some explicit conditions for $a_n$ which would determine whether $f$ is a Picard-0 function or a Picard-1 function?

Comment: This may be of use: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270804/surjective-entire-functions/270818#270818

Comment: The “Picard-1-functions” are exactly the functions of the form $f(z) = c  + e^{g(z)}$ where $g$ is entire. As explained in the MO answer, this implies that $f$ is of integral or of infinite order, but that is only a necessary condition. But I am fairly sure that there is no formula which takes the coefficients as input and *exactly* determines if $f$ has an exceptional value or not.

Comment: @Martin R How can it be determined whether e.g. the sine series is of the form $c+e^{g(z)}$ before knowing whether it is Picard-0 or Picard-1?

Comment: There are many ways to show that $\sin(z)$ is surjective, the simplest is perhaps to solve the equation $\sin(z) = (e^{iz} - e^{-iz})/2i = w$ explicitly (it is a quadratic equation in $e^{iz}$). I am currently not aware of a way to determine the surjectivity of the sine function from its Taylor series only.

Comment: @Pythagoras What does $\rho$ stand for in the answer you linked?

Comment: @Nomas: $\rho$ is the *order* of an entire function and $\sigma$ its *type,* see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type

Comment: There is a simple limit formula that relates coefficients with order, (see link above) so if the result of that is finite but not integral non zero, the function is surjective ( except in the trivial case of order zero and function constant); note also that in the case of finite non zero integral order, a non surjective function must be the exponential of a polynomial of degree precisely the order plus a constant so that gives strong conditions on the coefficients (essentially they depend on $d+1$ parameters, where $d$ is the order) so usually makes it obvious either way

Comment: For example for $\sin$ one gets order $1$ by the formula so if it weren't surjective it would be $ce^{az}+b$ and then by conjugate invariance one gets $c,a$ real, but then $a$ must be zero looking on the real axis at plus minus infinity etc

Comment: @Conrad What do you mean by conjugate invariance?

Comment: Taylor coefficients are real (equivalent to $f(\bar z)=\bar f(z)$ - sometimes these are called "real" analytic functions but that can get confusing as their image is not real, but the image of the real axis is real

Comment: Similar proof as above gives $e^z+P(z)$ surjective for any non-constant polynomial $P$ (otherwise you get $e^z-ce^{az}=b-P(z)$ and that forces first LHS zero by taking limits at infinity and that implies $P$ constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call “Picard-1-functions” are exactly the functions of the form
$$ \tag{1}
 f(z) = c + e^{g(z)}
$$
with a complex constant $c$ and an entire function $g$.

I am not aware of a  condition on the Taylor coefficients $(a_n)$ of $f$ which is necessary and sufficient for $f$ to be surjective or not. This might be difficult because small changes in a coefficient change the behavior: $e^z$ is not surjective, but
$$
 f(z) = e^z + a z^n
$$
*is* surjective for any positive integer $n$ and arbitrary non-zero complex number $a$.

There are some *necessary* conditions which are related to the [*order* and *type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type) of entire functions (compare [Surjective entire functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270804/surjective-entire-functions/270818#270818) on Math Overflow).

The *order* of an entire function is defined as
$$ \tag{2}
\rho = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log \log M(r, f)}{\log r}
$$
where $M(r, f) = \sup \{ |f(z)| : |z| \le r \}$. The order can be computed from the Taylor coefficients as
$$ \tag{3}
\rho = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log n}{- \log |a_n|} \, .
$$

For entire functions of positive and finite order $\rho$, the *type* is defined as
$$ \tag{4}
\sigma = \limsup \frac{M(r, f)}{r^\rho} 
$$
which is related to the coefficients via
$$ \tag{5}
 \sigma = \frac{1}{e \rho} \limsup_{n \to \infty} n |a_n|^{\rho/n} \, .
$$

Now, if $f$ is not surjective and of finite order, then the function $g$ in $(1)$ is necessarily a polynomial, and that implies that the order $\rho$ in $(2)$ is an integer, and the type $\sigma$ in $(4)$ is positive.

Using the identities $(3)$ and $(5)$, we get *necessary* conditions on the (growth of the) coefficients $(a_n)$ for $f$ to be not surjective.